# Remove map entries based on collection of values - how to do it in a Groovy way?

Tags: groovy, collections

Is there a Groovy way of dropping elements from `a` that match values in `b`?

```
def a = [1:"aa", 2:"bb", 3:"cc", 4:"dd"]
def b = [ "bb", "dd"]

expected output : [1:"aa", 3:"cc"]
```

I am currently using 2 nested for loops to solve this. I am wondering if Groovy has a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

#### For Groovy < `2.5.0`

You can use a single `Map.findAll()` method to do that:

```
a.findAll { k,v -> !(v in b) }
```

However, keep in mind that this method does not modify existing `a` map, but it creates a new one instead. So if you want to modify map stored in `a` variable you will have to reassign it.

```
a = a.findAll { k,v -> !(v in b) }
```

#### For Groovy >= `2.5.0`

Groovy version 2.5.x introduced a new default method for `Map` - `removeAll` which takes a predicate and removes elements from input map based on this predicate.

```
a.removeAll { k,v -> v in b}
```

Comment: @manish, or if you want to modify `a` you could use `a.removeAll { k, v -> v in b }`

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov `Map.removeAll` was added in Groovy 2.5.0, so it depends on the Groovy version that is used.